# Allow Access origin Issue With Rest Api For Patch Method

Tags: rest-api, apexrest

I created Rest api for the User details with Get and PATCH Methods.
I am able Access Get method.But for PATCH METHOD it is giving 405 METHOD NOT Allowed.I added headers for accessing the All Methods.

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/UserDetails/*')
global class UserDetails
{
    @HttpGet
    global static List<User> getUserDetails() 
    {

        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;

        res.addHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
        res.addHeader('Cache-Control','no-cache');
        res.addHeader('Access-Control-Max-Age','1728000');
        res.addHeader('Accept', '*');
        res.addHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
        res.addHeader('Accept','application/json');
        res.addHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS');
        res.addHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Content-Type, Accept');

        //String ID = req.requestURI.substring(req.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        String Id= RestContext.request.params.get('UserId');

        List<User> Users= [SELECT Id, Name, Username, CommunityNickname FROM User where Id=:Id];

        return Users;
    }

    @HttpPatch
    global static String updateUser(List<InputData> request)
    {
         try 
         {
             if(!(request.Size() > 0))
                 throw new CustomException('Input should not be empty'); 

            for(InputData data : request) 
            {
                User UserDetail= [SELECT Id,FirstName,LastName,Username FROM User where Id=:data.userId];

                UserDetail.FirstName=data.FirstName;
                UserDetail.LastName=data.LastName;  

                Update UserDetail;
            }

            return 'User details Updated';
       }
       catch(Exception e) 
       {
           return e.getMessage();
       }
    }

    global Class InputData
    {
        webService String userId { get; set; } 
        webService String FirstName { get; set; }
        webService String LastName { get; set; }
    }

    public Class CustomException extends Exception {}  
}
```

I am getting Responce as
 Raw Response

> HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
>
> Date: Mon, 07 Mar 2016 17:35:28 GMT
>
> Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: default-src https:; script-src 
>   https: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src https:
>   'unsafe-inline'; img-src https: data:; font-src https: data:;
>   report-uri /_/ContentDomainCSPNoAuth?type=mydomain Set-Cookie:
>   BrowserId=GHdQQhb3TfO5IwEJ0mw1og;Path=/;
>   Domain=.salesforce.com;Expires=Fri, 06-May-2016 17:35:28 GMT
>
> Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
>
> Allow: GET,HEAD
>
> Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
>
> Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>
> [ {   "errorCode" : "METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED",   "message" : "HTTP Method
>   'PATCH' not allowed. Allowed are GET,HEAD" } ]

Can any one suggest me where i am doing wrong in this API. It is very urgent.Please Help me

Comment: how you are calling your method ?

Comment: In workbench i am selecting the PATCH method and running this api it is giving this error. I try to send response as {"request" :[{"UserId":"005L0000002iC3J",
"FirstName":"Sssss",
"LastName":"uuuu"
}]}

Comment: We developed HTML Native app for our client. In html we are running all api's for fletching the data.Previously all api's getting this Allow Cross Origin issue.After adding the Headers all are working. In this api it is allowing get method so we are able to login.But we are not able to Update  the User details. When we try to update this it is giving XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://sfvud-varian.cs8.force.com/MPP/services/apexrest/UserDetails. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Origin 'https://209.160.65.49:1095' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405. This is the error i am getting

Comment: HI Himanshu can u please suggest me how to give access for the Patch

Comment: I don't think this an ip issue. try to run api from rest client

Comment: If i disabled the security from browser it is working fine.But it should allow with security. I set the Headers on POSTMAN it is working fine. This is the main issue i am facing

Comment: i am not getting it. how you are enabling setting in browser ?